Journey Builder Usecase
I have a scenario where I need to know that if a customer is in the running journey and now customer is saying that he/she should not receive any email then how can I remove that one particular record from the running journey without pausing or stopping the journey?

To achieve this, you can use the exit criteria function in journey builder. Moreover, the attribute and data extension you use in the exit criteria should be mapped in the data designer. This allows you to change and act on values after the subscriber has entered the journey.

Adding to this correct answer: if the emails in the journey are using commercial send classification and subscriber has All Subscriber status set to Unsubscribed, emails will also not be sent

Thanks August Rimmen and Lukas Lunow for your answers.
I wanted to add on to the answers and ask that if we haven't configured the exit criteria function in journey builder and also we are not using commercial send classfication in the emails then how can we achieve the scenario that I mentioned in my question?
Thanks in advance.

There are a few options. If this is a one-time thing you can always eject subscribers manually based on SubscriberKey through the health panel in Journey Builder. This is a very manual process. If you need something more automated I would suggest looking into a combination of SQL and APIs. The contactExitRequest allows you to eject up to 50 subscribers.
Documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/references/mc_rest_contacts/contactExitRequest.html

Thanks for the clear explanation and suggesting the automated process too.
This helps!!!

Additionally, I believe you could add an Exclusion Script to the respective email activities. If you have an exclusion data extension that any opt-outs are logged to for this particular journey, you can reference this in your script. You can edit the email activity after the journey has been started, to add the exclusion script by going to the email > Activity Summary > Delivery Options > Exclusion Script. More info: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384149&type=1
